# Sum of numbers in string is not correct - cs50, basic C

Tags: c, string, sum, cs50

First time asking a question here. I'm taking an online course (edx - cs50) learning very basic C. I am working through a program on checking the validity of a credit card number.

Although I'm sure my code needs to be cleaned up (and I am open to all critiques and suggestions!), my main quest has to do with the way I am summing the number.

Here are the two scenarios I go through with my program followed by the issues I'm having.

1. Ask user for credit card -- I enter 13 digits.
2. Enter a valid number.
3. My "check value" sum at the bottom of the program is correct and equals 13 '1's.

My second scenario:

1. Ask user for credit card -- I enter 2 digits.
2. While loop states it is invalid, and asks for a new number -- I enter **13** '1's.
3. My "check value" sum at the bottom of the program equals **32780**.

Code:

```
int main(void) {
    // Initialize string for CCNumber
    char s[16];

    // User input
    printf("Enter your credit card number, without dashes: ");
    long long CCNumber = GetLongLong();
    sprintf(s, "%lld", CCNumber);
    int l = strlen(s);
    printf("1st  check:%d\n", l);

    // Check valid CC length
    while (l < 13 || l > 16 || l == 14) {
        printf("Try again:\n");
        long long CCNumber = GetLongLong();
        sprintf(s, "%lld", CCNumber);
        l = strlen(s);
    }

    // Check CCNumber length
    printf("2nd check:%d\n", l);

    // Put number into an array
    int number[l];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        number[i] = s[i] - '0';
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = l - i; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += number[i];
    }

    printf("Check value: %d\n", sum);
}
```

I am a little confused on what is happening with the sum -- why are 13 '1's that I enter being returned as 32780? Thanks for all help or tips.

Here is the output I am getting:

```
retry@ubuntu:~/Documents/EDX$ ./credit2
Enter your credit card number, without dashes: 1111111111111
1st  check:13
2nd check:13
Check value: 13
retry@ubuntu:~/Documents/EDX$ ./credit2
Enter your credit card number, without dashes: 11
1st  check:2
Try again:
1111111111111
2nd check:13
Check value: 32780
```

Comment: In your last `for` loop, you initialise `i` with an expression that references the variable itself. Did you mean `int i = l - 1`? Why do you loop backwards?

Comment: M Oehm -- it's part of checking if the number is valid, which I haven't implemented yet. I'll have to multiply every other number starting with the second to last digit.

Answer (score 0):

`for (int i = l - i; i >= 0; i--)`  i = 13 on the first iteration, but your declaration for `number` is:

```
int number[l]
```

This gives you access to array indexes 0..12 (when `l=13`), and 13 is beyond the end of the array... this causes the addition of a random value from elsewhere in memory beyond the last place of the stack allocation for `number`.

If you change the loop to:

```
for (int i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Then you will not have this problem.

Comment: Hmm, M Oehm, didn't realize I'm referencing 'i' itself. I think you're right, I should be decrementing by 1 each time, not the variable itself. I'll try this.

Comment: That was it -- just had to change it to l - 1 instead of -i. Seems obvious now -- thanks for the assistance!